# Consecutive numeric-style citation call-outs. Why doesn't LaTeX create a numeric range, e.g., "1-4"?

Tags: citing

I have several citations at the same place with successive citation numbers, but LaTeX does not use a hyphen to connect the first one and the last one. For example,

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
    It has been shown in many experiments \cite{paper1,paper2,paper3,paper4} that ...

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\bibliography{my_refs}
\end{document}
```

What I want is "It has been shown in many experiments [1-4]", but what LaTeX gives is "It has been shown in many experiments [1,2,3,4]".

Comment: It does what the style instructs it to do...

Comment: Hi @mickep, I used elsarticle-num-names.bst

Comment: @JasperHabicht, I do not want to add an en dash by hand, but it should be generate by Latex

Comment: @JasperHabicht Since this is a numbered style, APA requirements don't matter, since APA is an author-year style.

Comment: @JasperHabicht - It's not the bib style but the citation management package that determines the output of`\cite{paper1,paper2,paper3,paper4}`. With the `natbib` package (and, of course, a bib style that can generate numeric-style citation call-outs), it's necessary to generate the desired output, viz., `[1--4]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set the tag "natbib", so I'll assume you're using the `natbib` citation management package -- along with a bibliography style that can generate numeric-style citation call-outs.

If these assumptions are valid, all you need to add is to specify the option `compress` when loading the `natbib` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

% Create a sample bib file on the fly:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{paper1,author="A", title="B", year=3001}
@misc{paper2,author="C", title="D", year=3002}
@misc{paper3,author="E", title="F", year=3003}
@misc{paper4,author="G", title="H", year=3004}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % or some other suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\cite{paper1,paper2,paper3,paper4}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: In response to a request to do so, the OP has now augmented the information provided in the query to reveal which document class is in use: `elsarticle`. Since this document class loads the `natbib` citation management package automatically, it is necessary to specify the option `compress` as an argument of the `\documentclass` directive:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,compress]{elsarticle}
```

Comment: I added '\usepackage[numbers,compress]{natbib}' in the preamble, but it gives an error: Option clash for package natbib.

Comment: @jsxs -- You've failed so far to mention which document class you employ. Will you please provide this critically-important missing piece of information? Alternatively, does your preamble try to load the `natbib` package (at least) twice?

Comment: please see my update, thank you very much!

Comment: @jsxs - please see the addendum I posted.